# REQUISIÇÕES JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Se faço uma Requisição para o meu bean e esse bean irá fazer uma consulta em uma lista. Uma lista de cpf por exemplo.

Eu consigo atualizar o cliente desta requisição a cada resultado deste loop feito no bean? Pergunto isso porque muitas vezes essa lista pode ser extensa e o cliente terá que aguardar.

Alguém teria alguma alternativa?

---

Desde já agradeço a resposta. Vou tentar ser mais específico.
Importo uma lista em excel através de upload de cpf(apenas cpfs)... para uma list que é formada por cpf{numero,eValido,nome,dtNasc} (eValido=false,nome="",Data=null) então essa lista é atualizada no meu front. Feito isso tem um botão iniciar. ao chamar o método no bean muitas vezes pelo fato dessa lista de cpf ser muito grande, só obtenho o resultado(visualização) no final da execução deste método. Gostaria que durante esse loop quando fosse consultatado cada cpf e retornasse se é válido, nome e data de nascimento, retornasse esse resultado parcial no cliente e continuasse a execução do restante do loop digamos assim.. Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1):

É possível atualizar o bean através do [Ajax](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml). Utilizando [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/index.xhtml) você pode utilizar um componente que realiza paginação, como o [Datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) e assim esse controle seria feito pelo framework na view. Já na consulta, seria necessário implementar um mecanismo de paginação para limitar o número de resultados trazidos. No caso de utilizar [JPA](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-jpa-java-persistence-api/28173), você pode seguir esse [exemplo](http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination), utilizando os métodos `setFirstResult` e `setMaxResults` para controlar os resultados trazidos por página da Datatable.